# Why does CMake state that an imported target is not built by project when if (TARGET ...) returns true?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create a CMake project that uses GLEW as a dependency.

Here is my sub-directory CMakeLists.txt file.

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)

target_include_directories(GLEW::glew, INTERFACE, GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS)
#debug to check if target created in cmake
if (TARGET GLEW::glew)
    message("GLEW is a target")
endif()
```

The target_include_directories throws the following error message.
**CMake Error at external/CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_include_directories):
Cannot specify include directories for target "GLEW::glew," which is not
built by this project.**

But the output message **"GLEW is a target"** is generated, indicating that GLEW::glew was a generated import target. I'm not sure how CMake could confirm GLEW::glew is a target through the TARGET expression, and still throw this error.

Can anyone reconcile this apparent contradiction?

(Note: I think the target_include_directories call is unnecessary, as the FindGLEW.cmake module file should set the required properties. However, I would still like to understand the above behavior.)

For debug, I set GLEW_VERBOSE in the CMakeLists.txt before calling find package, as show below:

```
set(GLEW_VERBOSE TRUE)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

I can see from the logs that the target is build:

```
-- FindGLEW: did not find GLEW CMake config file. Searching for libraries.
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_USE_STATIC_LIBS: FALSE.
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/include
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/include
-- FindGLEW: CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES for SHARED: .so;.a
-- FindGLEW: CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES for STATIC: .so
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY_RELEASE: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.a
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY_DEBUG: GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_SHARED_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_STATIC_LIBRARY: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.a
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_VERSION_MAJOR: 2
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_VERSION_MINOR: 2
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_VERSION_MICRO: 0
-- FindGLEW: GLEW_VERSION: 2.2.0
**-- FindGLEW: Creating GLEW::glew imported target.
-- FindGLEW: Creating GLEW::GLEW imported target.**
```

This combined with TARGET expression evaluating true indicates to me that the target GLEW::glew is being built. Yet I still get the same error message mentioned before.

Comment: I do not understand the confusion. The logical conclusion from your post is that the assumption `TARGET expression evaluating true indicates to me that the target GLEW::glew is being built` is just false. No, it is not build, it is _imported_. Also you are asking XY questions. Why not ask about why `target_include_directories(GLEW::glew, INTERFACE, GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS)` generates an error? Have you researched CMake language? Do you think arguments are separated by a comma? Do you have a directory named `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS`? Why are you adding a directory named `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS` to `GLEW::glew`?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Are you aware that the error message is about `GLEW::glew,` target not `GLEW::glew`? With that, the question doesn't make sense. `GLEW::glew,` is not build, because it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because something is a target does not mean it will be built by the generated buildsystem. Imported targets are **by definition**... imported- that is- already built- not built by the generated buildsystem- imported into the generated buildsystem. [Related docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries).